# When 'sizeof' is applied on a string, why does it return its size (as strlen)?

Tags: c

If I have a string:

```
char s1[]="hello, how are you?";
printf("%d\n",sizeof(s1));
```

it prints the exact, right number of characters, 20. But if I have a string initialized by a pointer:

```
char *s2;
s2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
strcpy(s2,s1);
printf("%d\n",sizeof(s2));
```

it prints the size of a pointer, which depends on the machine (on mine, 8).
So why is it 8 bytes for s2, and 20 bytes for s1, since they are the same string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are not the same string, or even the same type. `char s2[]` is an **array**, it has the size of the sum of the size of its elements. `char *s2` is a **pointer**, it has the size of a pointer.

`sizeof()` is (in C89) a compile-time operator that must know the size of it's argument at compile time.  Since a **pointer** can come from anywhere, `sizeof()` can't know the size of the allocated memory, but an **array** is always given a size at compile time (except for C99's VLA's), and `sizeof()` can then return the size of that memory.

Comment: Understood, so the size of s2[] it's known at compile time, but it's memory location can't change.Indeed if I try re-assigning s2 to another memory location it gives an error.Instead a pointer is dynamic, the location is decided runtime.That's why,I understand now.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that arrays are not pointers; in one case you get the size of an array and in the other the size of the pointer to it.

The `sizeof` operator applied to a string yields the number of characters of the string including the trailing null character.

In the second case, you are not computing the size of a string but instead the size of a pointer to a string, so it yields the size of the pointer type.

```
char *s2;
s2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
strcpy(s2,s1);
```

This code is wrong; you are allocating room for only one char. You need to allocate space for the entire string:

```
char *s2;
s2 = malloc(sizeof s1);
strcpy(s2, s1);
```

Finally, regarding the `strlen` function (since you mentioned it): the length of a string is not the same value as the size of a string. The length of a string is the number of characters preceding the trailing, terminating null character while the size of a string is the number of characters of the string including the null character.

Answer (score 3):

`char s2[]` is a statically allocated array, it's all on the stack, and the operator `sizeof` has an overloaded version that can measure the size of a statically-allocated array, as delnan commented.

`char* s2` is a pointer and the allocated string (with `malloc`) is on the heap.

Comment: I wouldn't say there's a special "overload" for `char` arrays. There's nothing special about `char` arrays, and the only thing "special" about arrays as opposed to pointers is that the former have a (compile-time, if we ignore VLAs) size, and *of course* `sizeof` uses that information.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` returns the size of the data type you pass in. When you pass in `char[20]` that data type takes up 20 bytes but when you pass in `char*` that takes a machine word.

Answer (score 1):

This is by definition. When the `sizeof` operator is applied to arrays, it will be replaced by the compiler with the length of the array (in the compilation stage). When it's applied to a pointer, the compiler replaces it with the size of the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding the fact that you didn't allocate enough memory in the second case (it should have been `malloc(<number of characters to be stored>+1)`), the two `s2` are not the same thing.

In the first case, you have an *array*; you are using the special string-initialization syntax that results in an array of the correct size already initialized to that string. `sizeof` on an array results correctly in its size (in units of `char`).

In the second case, you have a *pointer*, which knows nothing about how big is what it is pointing to. `sizeof` on a pointer returns the size of the pointer, which, on 32 bit machines, is 4 bytes=32 bit, because 32 bits are all the space needed to store a pointer to every possible memory location in a 32 bit address space.