# Abort trap 6 after successful call to function

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to understand exactly why I'm getting an abort trap: 6 on execution of a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *Asc2Hex(char *data, char *buffer);
char *Hex2Asc(char *data, char *buffer);

int main(void)
{
    char *convert = "546865206f6e652065796564206f6e6520686f726e656420666c79696e6720707572706c652070656f706c65206561746572206973206120667572727920707572706c65207075737379";
    char  buffer[sizeof(convert)*2]; 
    char *test = Hex2Asc(convert, buffer);
    printf("Data: %s\nSize: %lu bytes\n", test,strlen(test));
    return 0;
}

int hex_to_int(char c){
    if(c >=97)
        c=c-32;
    int first = c / 16 - 3;
    int second = c % 16;
    int result = first*10 + second;
    if(result > 9) result--;
    return result;}

int hex_to_ascii(char c, char d){
    int high = hex_to_int(c) * 16;
    int low = hex_to_int(d);
    return high+low;
}

char *Hex2Asc(char *data, char *buffer){
    int i, x, len = strlen(data);
    char buf = 0;
    for(i = 0,x = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(i % 2 != 0){
            sprintf(buffer+x,"%c",hex_to_ascii(buf,data[i]));
            x++;
        }else{
            buf = data[i];
        }
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

The abort trap 6 does NOT happen if I pass the string to be converted as char convert[] = ...

i.e.:

```
char convert[] = "546865206f6e652065796564206f6e6520686f726e656420666c79696e6720707572706c652070656f706c65206561746572206973206120667572727920707572706c65207075737379";
```

Just trying to understand why. This also causes a headache because I need to be able to take a pointer to a character array and pass it to the function. I have another function - Asc2Hex - which has the same exact issue (obviously) - as it's coded essentially the same. Any pointers, no pun intended?

```
Process 23540 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0xfc5ce9, 0x00007fff90e83866 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00007fff90e83866 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10:
-> 0x7fff90e83866:  jae    0x7fff90e83870            ; __pthread_kill + 20
   0x7fff90e83868:  movq   %rax, %rdi
   0x7fff90e8386b:  jmpq   0x7fff90e80175            ; cerror_nocancel
   0x7fff90e83870:  ret    
(lldb) c
Process 23540 resuming
Process 23540 exited with status = 0 (0x00000000) 
(lldb)
```

Comment: `sizeof(convert)` is really small, since `convert` is pointer. So you get a buffer overflow and a memory corruption, that can lead to unpredictable results. I would suggest changing type of `convert` to `char[]`.

Comment: I didn't even realize that... So, I actually used strlen(); instead of sizeof, and that seems to have corrected the issue... But, what's odd is that I noticed that sizeof printed the length - 1 - I'm assuming sizeof() does not account for the trailing nul terminator?

Comment: @JonnyWhatshisface Other way around. `strlen` does not account for the terminator when runtime-computing the length of a string. It is always the length up-to, but not including, the terminator. `sizeof()` and the idea of a terminating char are unrelated. It expresses as the byte-length of the operand. If that operand is a `char` *array*, so be it. The content (terminated string or not) is irrelevant. `char str[256] = "hi";` will return `2` for `strlen`, and return `256` for `sizeof`. `char str[] = "hi";` will return still return `2` for strlen, but `3` for sizeof`; it declares a 3-char array.

Comment: Actually, I just realized something very funny. using strlen() on the pointer does return the correct length of the character array being pointed to, but doing sizeof on the pointer yields the byte count for the pointer address. Could using pointer de-referencing resolve this and return the length of the array that the pointer points to? I'm somewhat confused on that. I think I'll do some tinkering to ensure I have a better grasp on pointers and character arrays, because they seem to be biting me in the butt right now.

Comment: Apparently, sizeof() is not capable of returning the size of the data that a pointer points to - so seemingly, the only way I would be able to get the size in bytes would be to do a strlen on the pointer and divide by the sizeof the data type... ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When 'sizeof' is applied on a string, why does it return its size (as strlen)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953327/when-sizeof-is-applied-on-a-string-why-does-it-return-its-size-as-strlen)